# Avoiding postbacks on dynamically created controls

Tags: asp.net

I have a page in which controls are dynamically generated as the user navigates through a series of questions.

When they finish the form, they click a submit button, and I gather the information they entered and store it in a database.

Currently, I'm creating several of these controls with

```
.AutoPostBack = True
```

As a result, every time the user changes the text and tabs to the next field, a postback occurs, and the next field loses focus.

If I set

```
.AutoPostBack = False
```

then the focus problem goes away, but at the end when I gather the data, none of what the user entered in those controls is actually available to client side code, because it hasn't been posted yet.

I'd like to do one of the following:

1. Have one big postback at the end
2. Have standard postbacks without losing focus on controls as I leave them
3. Something else I haven't thought of...?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can store and retrieve data using viewstate between postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to dynamically created controls is ***when*** in the page lifecyle to add the controls. To retain viewstate and have the dynamic controls maintain the posted values, the controls need to be added no later than `OnInit()`.

In addition, the controls need to be re-added on ***every*** page load, postback or not. Regarding what @KennyZ said about guaranteeing the same ID for each control, as long as you are adding the same number of controls in the same order, .NET will guarantee the IDs are the same.

In regards to the `AutoPostBack` property, this is usually only set to True when we want to perform some action that is triggered by the user changing the value of the control. A common example is a drop-down list; depending on what the user selected, different data is loaded into, say, the details section of the page. So each time the user changes the value, we want to postback and fetch new data to display.

From my understanding of your use case, I would suggest one postback for the entire form.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since I messed with these, but I recall needing to re-add the dynamic controls (page load, or init?  I forget), making sure I guaranteed the same ID for each dynamically added control as it got when it was added, before I could access any of the user entered data from ViewState.

I also recall using SessionState to keep track of what I added so I knew what I needed to construct for ViewState.

It felt just as kludgy doing it then as it sounds describing it now.  Good luck.